# Windows failing to start after upgrading RAM sticks

Tags: windows, boot, memory, upgrade

I have recently upgraded the RAM in my desktop machine and now Windows is stuck on the Starting Windows screen. I cannot even start it in Safe Mode. But when I run Ubuntu 15.04 Linux it boots and works perfectly. Is this a driver issue? I cannot even fix Windows with repair mode. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and Windows 10 and neither will load. The correct amount of RAM is reported by Linux and the POST screen, so this is detected correctly. I hope there is a simple fix for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

I have the two 1600 RAM sticks in my computer and Ubuntu reports 12 gigabytes of RAM, but when I try to start Windows, it will shutdown and reboot my machine at the Starting Windows screen. I might have to run Memtest86 to test the RAM and see what the problem is. Or try and reinstall Windows.

Comment: You shouldn't need driver changes for that. How much ram did you have and how much do you have now? Also what PC? How many DIMMs? If you have more than one, it is possible that one is not properly seated or has a fault. Did you use an anti-static strap when installing?

Comment: I had 6 Gigabytes of RAM and now I have 16 Gigabytes. I installed DDR3 1600 RAM. But it is strange that I am using Ubuntu on the machine to type this and it is working perfectly with the system monitor showing 1.4 Gigabytes of RAM free out of 15.6 Gigabytes.

Comment: I have found the problem. I had two 1600 sticks and one 1333 stick in the machine. I removed the 1333 stick and Windows 7 came straight up. So that was the problem. Thanks for your comment too. But this was just me mixing up two types of RAM.

Comment: Hi John. We don't mark questions with "SOLVED" in the title on Super User or Stack Exchange in general. Instead, you should post a self-answer detailing what the solution was, possibly including steps you took to determine that it was the solution, and accept that answer by clicking the checkmark outline. You will be able to accept your own answer to your question after (IIRC) 48 hours. Note that comments are meant to be ephemeral, and can be deleted at any time, whereas questions and answers remain (provided that they are useful and relevant). Welcome to Super User.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that changed is the RAM, and Windows fails to boot, all signs point to bad RAM.  I have seen Linuxes boot and run with bad RAM... until it tries to write to the bad part of the RAM.

Try a memory testing tool like [MemTest86](http://www.memtest.org/).